# Setting a button text dynamically in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to set the text of a button  of a Dialog in jquery. I have 2 variables whose value will change dynamically. These values should be set to Button text. I have written the following code.

```
 var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

   var today = new Date();
   var month = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
   var nextMonth = monthNames[today.getMonth()+1];

  $( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: month,
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    },
    {
        text: nextMonth,
        click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    }
] });
```

});

But Form Dialog is not loading. Pls help me with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: can you post an HTML snippet? My guess is you copied the code from jquery sample and didn't change the selector `$( ".selector" )`

Comment: Can you possibly set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: you checked the console for possible errors?

Comment: @ftom2 Hi.. This is the HTML body I have written.
 <body>
<div id="selector" title="Pop Up" class = "selector">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
  Do u want to save the score?</p>
</div>
</body>

Comment: Please update your question with the code, don't post it in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, make sure you have added `jquery` and `jquery ui` reference and have `selector` `class` in your `html` markup, example

```
<div class="selector"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/AwzDD/1/)**

Update*

Please add `http://` in your js and css reference

One page example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="selector" title="Pop Up" class = "selector"> <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span> Do u want to save the score?</p> </div>
        <script>
            var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

            var today = new Date();
            var month = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
            var nextMonth = monthNames[today.getMonth() + 1];

            $(".selector").dialog({buttons: [
                    {
                        text: month,
                        click: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: nextMonth,
                        click: function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                ]});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the following references Manoj.<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Please add `http://` in your js and css reference, Answer updated with one page example

Answer (score 1):

Your div have `id="selector"` but in your jquery you call `$('.selector')` which is for class. So either change to:

```
<div class="selector"></div>
```

Or change your jquery code:

```
$( "#selector" ).dialog();
```